# undefined index using update statement

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to update a field in my database by adding to the original number value that is already in there. 
i have a system where staff are able to log in and update a the balance of a normal user. Currently i have a test user and staff. the users balance is set to 100. i have the following code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
$result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username ='$searchq'");
    if ($result){ 

        //fetch result set as object and output HTML
        if($obj = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            echo '<div class="booksearched">'; 
            echo '<form method="POST" id = "books" action="">';
            echo '<div class="book-content"><h3>Student Username: '.$obj->Username.'</h3>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<div class="book-content"><i>First Name: <b>'.$obj->FirstName.'</b></i></div>';
            echo '<div class="book-desc"><i>Last Name:<b> '.$obj->LastName.'</b></i></div>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<div class="book-qty"> Current Balance<b> '.$obj->Balance.'</b></div>';
            echo 'New Balance: <input type="number" name="newBalance" value = "1" min = "1" />';
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo '<button name="submit_btn" class="save_order">Top Up</button>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}

    $newBalance="";
$newBalance = $_POST['newBalance'];

if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ){
    $upsql = "UPDATE users SET Balance = Balance + '$newBalance' WHERE Username='" . $obj->Username . "'";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($upsql);
    $stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

Ive tried a few things however i kept getting an error saying:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: newBalance
```

Im not sure what ive done wrong.
Any idea how to fix it?

**Edit:** Full code

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<br>
<div id="books-wrapper">

<!-- #content to center the menu -->
<div id="content">
    <!-- This is the actual menu --> 
    <ul id="darkmenu">
          <li><a href="adminHome.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="addBook.php">New Books</a></li>
          <li><a href="adminSearch.php">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="updateBalance.php">Update Balance</a></li>
    </ul>


</div>
    <div id = "welcome" >
        Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['Username'];?>! <br> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </div>

<br><br>
    <h1 id = "mainHeader" >Update a Students Balance</h1>
<br>   
<div id = "balanceupdate">
<form id = "adsearch" action="updateBalance.php"  method="post">
    <input type="text" name ="search" placeholder="Search For a Student">
    <button name="submit" value="search">Search</button>
</form>
<br>
</div>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
$result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username ='$searchq'");
    if ($result){

        //fetch result set as object and output HTML
        if($obj = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            echo '<div class="booksearched">'; 
            echo '<form method="POST" id = "books" action="">';
            echo '<div class="book-content"><h3>Student Username: '.$obj->Username.'</h3>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<div class="book-content"><i>First Name: <b>'.$obj->FirstName.'</b></i></div>';
            echo '<div class="book-desc"><i>Last Name:<b> '.$obj->LastName.'</b></i></div>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<div class="book-qty"> Current Balance<b> '.$obj->Balance.'</b></div>';
            echo 'New Balance: <input type="number" name="newBalance" value = "1" min = "1" />';
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo '<button name="submit_btn" class="save_order">Top Up</button>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}

    $newBalance="";

    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']) && !empty($_POST['newBalance']) ){

        $newBalance = $_POST['newBalance'];

        $upsql = "UPDATE users SET Balance = Balance + '$newBalance' WHERE Username='" . $obj->Username . "'";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($upsql);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, you don't have a form element bearing the name attribute `search`. So you need to use `isset()` for `newBalance`, or place it below `if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ){`

Comment: i have a form at the top `<form action="search.php" id = "adsearch" method="post">
 <input type="text" name ="search" placeholder="search for a category">
 <button name="submit" value="search">Search</button>
</form>`

Comment: Then do what I mentioned in the latter part of my comment.

Comment: I've posted an answer below, to better show you what to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw my answer, but I had an extra bracket `(` too many in it and was removed. Reload my answer to see the slight change.

Answer (score 5):

It's throwing that notice because you need to place `$newBalance = $_POST['newBalance'];` inside `if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])){...}` and verify that it is not empty (or set).

```
$newBalance="";

if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']) && !empty($_POST['newBalance']) ){

$newBalance = $_POST['newBalance'];

    $upsql = "UPDATE users SET Balance = Balance + '$newBalance' 
              WHERE Username='" . $obj->Username . "'";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($upsql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

You can also use `isset($_POST['newBalance'])` instead of `!empty($_POST['newBalance'])`

---

Sidenote: You may want to add a submit type for your button.

```
echo '<button type="submit" name="submit_btn" class="save_order">Top Up</button>';
```

Yet, it may not be required; do try it if you're still experiencing problems.

---

**Edit:**

Under

```
echo '<div class="book-content"><h3>Student Username: '.$obj->Username.'</h3>';
```

add

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" value = "'.$obj->Username.'"  />';
```

then under

```
$newBalance = $_POST['newBalance'];
```

add

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

and modify your query to read as

```
$upsql = "UPDATE users SET Balance = Balance + '$newBalance' 
          WHERE Username='".$username ."'";
```

My quoting may be a bit off for

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" value = "'.$obj->Username.'"  />';
```

where you may have to change it to

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" value = '".$obj->Username."'  />';
```

---

**Edit #2:**

Another way to do this since you're already using sessions `<?=$_SESSION['Username'];?>` would be to assign a variable to it and pass it in your query.

```
$username = $_SESSION['Username'];

$upsql = "UPDATE users SET Balance = Balance + '$newBalance' 
          WHERE Username='".$username ."'";
```

---

**Edit #3:**

Where you have

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
```

replace it with

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

$student = $_POST['search'];
$_SESSION['student'] = $student;

echo $_SESSION['student']; // see what echos here
```

then in your query, do:

```
$upsql = "UPDATE users SET Balance = Balance + '$newBalance' 
          WHERE Username='".$student ."'";
```

- If that doesn't work, I don't know what else to do that will be of further help. My tests were conclusive and worked. Your query may be failing, I have no more ideas at this point.

---

Base yourself on this scenario:

```
$_POST['search'] = "student1";

$student = $_POST['search'];

$_SESSION['student'] = $student;

// echo $_SESSION['student'];

$student2 = $student;

echo $student2; // will echo student1
```

Comment: that seems to have gotten rid of the undefined index error but now im getting: 
`( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: obj line 78` and 
`( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` line 78

Comment: @resontant81 Your question's code only contains 39 lines which is only 1/2 of what the error on line number is. So, you'll need to figure out why that is, and how it's being fetched from your DB. That whole code block for the UPDATE query should be inside a `while` loop you may have somewhere.

Comment: @resontant81 You completely overwrote your question without marking it as an edit under your original question. Please re-edit and add it under, otherwise people will visit the question and stand at downvoting my answer. Do rollback and edit it under the original post. You also added my code in your new post. Don't do that.

Comment: @resontant81 Just remove one of the braces `}` from above `$newBalance="";` and place it under `$stmt->execute();` - I also did a rollback to your original post also with your full code under it.

Comment: No more errors but nothing is being added to the balance field in the database

Comment: @resontant81 Reload my answer and look under **Edit:**. Read it carefully. The quoting may be off for the hidden input, which is why I added 2 ways.

Comment: @resontant81 I made another edit where you can use the sessions array. Reload again and look under **Edit #2**. Where are you so far with what I've given you?

Comment: Just tried edit 1 which didnt seem to work either :/ 
will try edit 2 now.. 

Edit 2 doesnt work either

Comment: @resontant81 Do a `var_dump($_SESSION['Username'];` that should show you something. This should be working.

Comment: says `string '456' (length=3)` where 456 is the users login name

Comment: @resontant81 Replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and see if there are any errors. Plus, `456` is an existing username in DB, right? Do also `var_dump($_POST['newBalance']);` anything in there too? Make sure your column types are correct and long enough to accomodate the data.

Comment: yup 456 is an admin user and is currently stored in the session. However i dont want the admins balance to top up. I want the balance of the username thats typed in to the textbox to update. Also i dont receive any errors when i used the error code

Comment: @resontant81 Ok, I think I know what else is wrong here. You said you have another form on top, but that is out of the scope of your second form, which is why it's not being pulled in from the textbox. You need to place either add a hidden attribute in your first form like I included in my answer, or use only ONE form.

Comment: which hidden attribute would i add to the first form?

Comment: @resontant81 Ok, try `WHERE Username='".$searchq."'` since that will be taken from the found result. Least, that's the impression I get from your query.

Comment: @resontant81 Reload see **Edit #3:** - if that doesn't work, then you'll need to work the rest of your code to make it work. My tests were conclusive. Good luck.

Comment: when i echoed out `echo $_SESSION['student'];` it shows the username that was typed into the textbox. but edit 3 still doesnt work.